# How to make WCF web-service consumable by Team Foundation Server Web Hooks?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, tfs-2015

I'm having trouble with Team Foundation Server 2015 Web Hooks (https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/webhooks-and-vso-vs)
I can create web hook on TFS side and it successfully uses RequestBin WebService. But when I create the WCF Web service - have errors all the time. 
First of all I get @Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/json; charset utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml;charset utf-8'.(415)"
I've read a lot of articles and related questions here.
Tried to add Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" to .svc file. After it I've got 404 error while consuming service and no endpoint found while trying to open it's WSDL

So, my Interface is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace MyService
{
    // ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Команду "Переименовать" в меню "Рефакторинг" можно использовать для одновременного изменения имени интерфейса "IService1" в коде и файле конфигурации.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        string RollUp(string sData);

        // TODO: Добавьте здесь операции служб
    }


    // Используйте контракт данных, как показано в примере ниже, чтобы добавить составные типы к операциям служб.
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

My program is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace MyService
{
    // ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Команду "Переименовать" в меню "Рефакторинг" можно использовать для одновременного изменения имени класса "Service1" в коде, SVC-файле и файле конфигурации.
    // ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Чтобы запустить клиент проверки WCF для тестирования службы, выберите элементы Service1.svc или Service1.svc.cs в обозревателе решений и начните отладку.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
         public string RollUp(string sData)
        {
            return "Sucess " + sData;
        }
    }
}
```

my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!--Чтобы избежать раскрытия метаданных, до развертывания задайте следующим параметрам значение "false". -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- Чтобы при сбое получать подробные сведения об исключении для целей отладки, установите для нижеприведенного параметра значение true.  Перед развертыванием установите значение false, чтобы избежать раскрытия информации об исключении -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>        
        <behavior name="json">          
          <webHttp/>        
        </behavior>      
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>      
      <service name="MyService.Service1">        
        <endpoint name="jsonEP"                  
                  address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"                  
                  behaviorConfiguration="json"                  
                  contract="MyService.IService1"/>      
      </service>    
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        Для просмотра корневого каталога веб-приложения во время отладки установите значение true.
        Перед развертыванием установите значение false, чтобы избежать раскрытия сведений в папке веб-приложения.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And with all of this I get 404 error.

Hope someone can help me as I can't beat this web services for days and for now have no idea what to do.

Comment: 404 error means the page can't be found. Did you ever publish the WCF web service?

Comment: If you run Fiddler to check the URL you used, will you get any errors?

Comment: Yes, I publish my web service to IIS and can see it's wsdl there.

Comment: Fiddler, never used it. Can it check web service? If it checks only URL then - I see the wsdl, web-service is somewhere there.